# Versioning AWS Lambda Function

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, versioning

I have read some answers about similar topics but I was not satisfied with any of them.
We are deploying some code into AWS Lambda with a jar file which contains a version of the code like `name-of-my-app-14.jar`, the 14 is the Jenkins build number.
The problem I have is that I don't have a way to understand which version of the jar is currently deployed in AWS and it would be a nice to have.

This is the cloudformation fragment I have to create the lambda:

```
MyLambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: name-of-my-app.jar
      FunctionName: "my-function-name"
      Handler: "com.package.something.myapp.HandlerClass::handleRequest"
      MemorySize: 256
      Role: "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/some-role"
      Runtime: "java8"
      Timeout: 60
      Environment:
        Variables:
          SOME_VARIABLE: "value"
```

To deploy we download the jar with the version we want to deploy from our artifact repository, saving it as it is specified in the above template and we run:

```
aws cloudformation package --template-file myapp-stack.yaml --output-template-file tmp.yaml --s3-bucket my.bucket
aws cloudformation deploy --region my-region --template-file tmp.yaml --stack-name prod-myappstackname --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM --parameter-overrides Environment=prod --no-fail-on-empty-changeset
```

Comment: What about using the Jenkins build number as a tag for the Lambda? Are you deploying cloudformation with Jenkins?

Comment: @WarrenG that is exactly what I have just done :) We are deploying with a script so I have put a placeholder in the CF template that I am replacing with a sed and then replacing back when the deploy is done. I hoped in something less handcrafted though.

Comment: you can also use the Lambda [version](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-version.html)  and [alias](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-alias.html) features but it needs a little bit of coding

Comment: @RezaNasiri I have checked those out as well, but it looked very tricky for the pretty simple thing I needed.